# user in 'www-data' is unable to mkdir in Apache2 with Composer

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, magento

my objective is to install Magento with Composer

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2

Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.2.6)

In ProjectInstaller.php line 68:

  mkdir(): Permission denied  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

I have a user

```
magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ groups magento_user 
magento_user : magento_user www-data
```

I have apache2

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ ps aux | grep apache
root      1003  0.0  0.3 499316 30788 ?        Ss   15:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1066  0.0  0.2 501648 17608 ?        S    15:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1067  0.0  0.2 501648 17608 ?        S    15:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1068  0.0  0.2 501648 17608 ?        S    15:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1069  0.0  0.2 501648 17608 ?        S    15:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1070  0.0  0.2 501648 17608 ?        S    15:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
magento+  6363  0.0  0.0  14432  1004 pts/0    S+   17:07   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

shouldn't presence of `www-data` grant to my user full privilege on `var/www/html` ???

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Update

after messing around my current status is

```
magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ ls -ld
drwxrwsr-x 3 root root 4096 ott  2 12:30 .

magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ mkdir duck
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘duck’: Permission denied

magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ mkdir duck
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘duck’: Permission denied
```

Why I still don't have `rws`: read, write, (what the `s` stands for?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a group member doesn't automatically grant a user write permissions. Every file has a set of permissions in linux which permit / restrict reading/writing/execution for the **file owner**, **members of the owning group** and **others**.

You should check the permissions of a file like this

```
root@sergey-mint:~# ls -l /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3 Sep 28 14:54 /var/run/rsyslogd.pid
```

pay attention to `-rw-r--r--`, it shows that the owner has read/write permissions, members of the owning group have only read permission and all others have only read permission.

In your case you have a directory which is a little different, but, nonetheless, is a file. You can check directory permissions by adding `-d` flag to `ls` like this

```
ls -ld /var/www/html
```

to be able to write there with your **magneto_user** you should make sure the group owners have read, write and execute permissions. To do that run the following command `chmod g+rwx /var/www/html`

Comment: `drwxrwsr-x 3 root root 4096`, `magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ mkdir duck
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘duck’: Permission denied`, Why I still don't have `rws`: read, write, (what the s stands for?)?

Comment: The second `root` tells us that the group owner of the directory is the group **root**, therefore, you'll need to change it to **www-data** using the following command: `chgrp www-data /var/www/html` (please note that this won't change the group owner of the content that's already in the directory, it would just allow you to create new stuff there). And regarding the `s` flag in `rws` - it's called SGID bit. You can find more details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid